# Example of a subgroup of index two which contains a non square element

Tags: finite-groups, examples-counterexamples

If a finite group contains a subgroup H of index two, then every element of the group which is a square belongs to H. Is there a (simple) counterexample showing that not all the elements of H are necessarily squares?

Comment: Take a group of exponent $2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: of order at least 4 :-)

Comment: @JackSchmidt $(C_2)^{123456789}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even easier...  In the Klein 4-group, there are three subgroups of index 2, but only one element is a square.  (It's the identity.)

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the simplest example. You all gave abalian examples. I'm wondering if there is a "genuine" non abelian example ...

Comment: Well, the "(simple)" nonabelian examples are the symmetric groups, containing the alternating groups which contain all the squares.  So those won't work.  How broad are you willing to make the word "(simple)" to find an example?

Comment: Maybe not much broader than the simmetric groups because for example I did not know the existence of the notion of the "exponent" of a finite group before yesterday!

Answer (score 2):

Try $G=\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \{0,2\}$.  Now $(1,0)\in H$ is not a square.